# Question involving abs of integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Need help to get started on this question:

> Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
>
> a) Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then so the function $\left | f \right |$ (where $(\left | f \right |(x)$ is defined on to be $\left | f(x) \right |).$
>
> b) Prove that $\left | \int_{a}^{b} f\right |\leq \int_{a}^{b}\left | f \right |$.

My attempt: a) If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ integrable on $[a,b]$ then $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there is a $P$ of $[a,b]$ so that $BS(f,P)<\epsilon \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}(M_i-m_i)\Delta x_i< \epsilon $.

Given, $\left | M_i-m_i \right |\geq \left | M_i \right |-\left | m_i \right |$ for $i=1,2,...,n$.

And $0\leq M_i-m_i$ for $i=1,2,...,n$ $\Rightarrow M_i-m_i=\left |  M_i-m_i\right |$.

So we have with the same partitions,

$\left | M_i \right |-\left | m_i \right |\leq \left | M_i-m_i \right |=M_i-m_i\Rightarrow (\left | M_i \right |-\left | m_i \right |)\Delta x_i\leq (M_i-m_i)\Delta x_i$.

Since $\Delta x_i> 0$, summing up from $i=1,2,...,n$ gives us

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\left | M_i \right |-\left | m_i \right |)\Delta x_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}(M_i-m_i)\Delta x_i=BS(f,P)< \epsilon $ and since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\left | M_i \right |-\left | m_i \right |)\Delta x_i=BS(\left | f \right |,P)$.

For part b): Given $f\leq \left | f \right |$ and $-\left | f \right |\leq f$.

So if $f$ and $-|f|$ are integrable on $[a,b]$ then

$-\left | f \right |\leq f\leq \left | f \right |\Rightarrow \int_{a}^{b}-\left | f \right |\leq \int_{a}^{b}f\leq \int_{a}^{b}\left |f  \right |\Rightarrow -\int_{a}^{b}\left | f \right |\leq \int_{a}^{b}f\leq \int_{a}^{b}\left | f \right |\Rightarrow \left | \int_{a}^{b} f\right |\leq \left | f \right |$.

Comment: What kind of integration are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to use the box-sum criterion for a).

Comment: @AlexBecker I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution for part b) is correct. However part a) is not true. You need additional conditions; for example $f$ is bounded.

To see that this what you have is false consider a function $f$ that is defined on $[0,1]$ $f(x)=(-1)^{n}(n+1)$ if $x\in{}(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$ for some $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$ with $n>2$, $0$ otherwise.

$f$ is integrable since $\int_{0}^{1}{f}=\sum\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$ (this should follow from considering upper and lower Reimann sums.) . But then $\int_{0}^{1}{|f|}=\sum\frac{1}{n}$ so $|f|$ is not integrable.